# Do Magento 2 Integration OAuth Access Tokens Never Expire?

Tags: magento2, api, oauth

Hi I just want to make sure that if I created an integration via OAuth authentication

I would use the access token of which for Magento 2 API calls.  It is my experience that they never expire, is this claim absolutely true?

Insofar that the behavior is different from the admin and customer access tokens that do expire and have to regenerate a token else get a 401 error

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're absolutely right, Magento2 integration access tokens (also referenced as Bearer tokens) are not supposed to expire by default.

Their default lifetime is "Indefinite. It lasts until it is manually revoked."

See official documentation for reference : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html